# How to use list in WHERE IN in SQL code in Power bi?

Tags: sql, powerbi

I am trying to load a fraction of a table from SQL database in Power BI using SQL language. I want to use WHERE IN and apply a variable list of values for filtering (this helps to reduce loading time). Since the list is changing, I do not want to write the filter values to the formula.

I tried this formula:

```
Source = Sql.Database("server", "database", [Query="SELECT header FROM report WHERE header IN ("&List&")"])
```

I get an error message about Text and List mismatch:

> Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator & to types Text and List.

This works, but requires direct typing the filtering values in the formula:

```
Source = Sql.Database("server", "database", [Query="SELECT header FROM report WHERE header IN ('Item1', 'Item2')"])
```

How can the list be transformed to text? What would be the correct syntax? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Text.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-combine) to transform your list to comma separated string of values. So your code will look like this:

```
Source = Sql.Database("server", "database", [Query="SELECT header FROM report WHERE header IN (" & Text.Combine(List, ",") & ")"])
```

If you need to quote the list values, try this way (but note my comment bellow!):

```
Source = Sql.Database("server", "database", [Query="SELECT header FROM report WHERE header IN ('" & Text.Combine(List, "','") & "')"])
```

Comment: This looks a step better, but throws another error:
```DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: Invalid column name 'Item2'```

Comment: If your list contains not numbers, but texts, then you need to quote them (otherwise the database engine will try to find objects with these names, thus the error you get). You need to add leading and trailing single quote, and change the list separator to include leading and trailing quotes too. But in general this is dangerous and considered a bad idea. What if some of these values contains quotes? Where these values comes from? Can someone inject some malicious value in the list? My advice is to review your design. For example put these values in the DB and join with this table.

Comment: Putting the values in the DB would be too slow for the inteded purpose. Evaluated data is ERP master data, so I decided to apply your suggestion with the single quotes, which works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Note, you don't need to embed SQL queries for this behavior. If you just load the table normally through the GUI editor and apply a filter to a column, that filter will be "folded" back to the SQL database engine for evaluation. "Folding" is the name for a piece of technology in Power Query/M where an M query can be translated into the language of the data source, so that e.g. filtering operations are performed in your SQL database, rather than in Power Query. You can always check what query is being generated for SQL sources by right-clicking on an applied step and selecting *View Native Query*.

If you really need to interpolate a list into a string, @AndreyNikolov's answer is the path to take.

Comment: The reason for trying to embed the filter to SQL query is that the whole table is loaded first if I filter it in the following step. "View Native Query" just lists the filtered items in the code in my case. Thanks for the insight though!

Comment: The whole table is not loaded upfront. A sample of up to 1000 rows is loaded in the query editor - you'll get 1000 unfiltered rows, then filter it. When you process the model, you would see only the rows meeting the criteria leaving the server that your SQL database is running on. Seriously, try it: connect to database table; filter on literal values in Power Query; close and apply; after that's done, start a trace on SQL so you can capture queries running; then hit refresh in Power BI. You'll see a SQL query come through with your literal predicates (applied in M code) in the `WHERE` clause.